# javascript error while loading the document

Tags: javascript

Im trying to run the below script to understand the Javascript object and inheritance but don't see anything being displayed.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(

                function Person(){
                    alert('New Person Created');
                }


                Person.prototype.sayHello = new function(){
                    alert('Hello');
                };

                var x = new Person();
                x.sayHello();

                var newfunction = x.sayHello;
                newfunction.call(Person);

            );
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should get used to spotting errors in the log, that’s your first lesson :)

Answer (score 1):

`$` is defined in jQuery, you need to include jQuery library before using the `$`

you can include jquery library using cdn like this,

```
<script src ="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first line of your script is jQuery. If you want to use jQuery you should include it first (based on what you have written I strongly suspect you don't need or want it just yet).

Alternatively, just drop the `$(document).ready` part and its {}s and that should get you going.

Also, take a look at your developer tools menu and get your JavaScript console open. It will have told you about this error.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a construct like `$(document)`, you are calling a function `$`, which is defined as jQuery.  You need a `<script>` tag in your document to load the correct version of jQuery.  Also, check your browser console.  You will see an error there about `$`

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can see wrong is that you are trying to use the jQuery library, but you've never actually included it.